# Elasticsearch reindex gets stuck

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

**Context**

We have two Elasticsearch clusters with 6 and 3 nodes each. The cluster with 6 nodes is the one we use in production environment and we use the one with 3 nodes for testing purposes. (We have the same problem in both clusters). All the nodes have the following characteristics:

- Elasticsearch 7.4.2
- 1TB HDD disk
- 8 GB RAM

In our case, we need to reindex some of the indexes. Those indexes have billions of documents and a size between 50GB and 250GB.

**Problem**

Whenever we start reindexing, internally or from a remote source, the task starts working correctly but it reaches a point where it stops reindexing, without apparent reason. We can´t see anything in the logs. The task is not cancelled or anything, it only stops reindexing documents, it looks like the task gets stuck. We tried changing GC strategies, we used CMS and Shenandoah but nothing changes.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: How many Docs does each index have? did you have check network stability? in some point do you have high average load (cpu)?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I followed your recommendations. At first we got an SocketTimeoutException. We resolved that changing socket_timeou value from 30s (default value) to 10 minutes, adding "socket_timeout": "10m" on the reindex request. Once we changed that, we are facing the same problem. The reindex task gets stuck and we can't see anything in our logs. We are as we were before. The task is not cancelled or anything, it only stops reindexing documents, it looks like the task gets stuck.

Answer (score -2):

It's difficult to find the RCA of these issues without debugging it and with the little information you provided(missing cluster and index configuration, index slow logs information, elasticsearch error logs, Elasticsearch hot threads to name a few).